# Click button until element is visible (click more button)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want in jquery to click a load more button until an element is visible on screen. The button load more makes an ajax call to add elements on the screen. I am trying with a do while loop but it is not working  and crashing the browser. Thanks for any suggestion!

```
// new-element not visible at first, I have to click the button load more many times for it to show
do{
  // clicking button load more (ajax call adding dynamically more elements on the screen)
  $('.button-load-more').click();

}while($('.new-element').length == 0 )
```

Comment: you should call `$('.button-load-more').click();` when ajax call completes

Comment: I wouldn't use do/ while for this.. I'd use jquery show/hide instead. I'd say a little rework of your code would be in order (emphasis on small).. If you don't want to hide it you could disable the button either.

Comment: Reminder:  javascript is **single threaded** so while your `while` loop is running, the browser can't process the ajax response, so doesn't update the DOM and your element will never appear.

Comment: While this approach is not ideal, you could change it to use `setTimeout`, eg `(function keeploading() { /*ajax call here */; if ($('.new-element').length == 0) setTimeout(keeploading, 500)})();`

Comment: Thanks everyone,  @freedomn-m your code helped to do what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helps you.

```
$(document).on('click','.button-load-more',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
      success:function(data){
         $('.button-load-more').hide().prop('disabled',true);
      }
   });
});
```